# Issue in running an exe on mac using wine bottler since the exe needs access to system32 folder on windows

Tags: wine

I have a command line interface exe that works on windows. This basically gets the PID and VID of the attached HID (Example a headset connected via USB) and I can interact with the connected USB using some commands.

I need to get the same thing to work on mac. At the moment, I can get the exe to launch on macosx using Wine bottler . But the connection to the headset is not happening because accessing DriverStore on mac might be different. Is there any way for me to get this to work?

I need this to work since my automation framework works on mac.